# DhtmlxGrid - Scrolling to the right end results in shift between header and body

Tags: dhtmlx

I'm experiencing the problem mentioned here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2521 with dhtmlxGrid. I've added below code

```
grid.splitAt((fixedColumnCount + 1)); grid.enableSmartRendering(true);
```

any help?

-Ashwath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your problem cannot be reconstructed locally.
Most problably the additional custom css on your page causes the problem.
Please, try to apply:

```
table.hdr{
    table-layout: fixed !important;
}
```